# What's wrong with my updated message delete button?

Tags: php

I'm trying to upgrade my code to delete a selected message. Below is my existing code and I want to change it,

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete" />
<input type="submit" name="deletebtn" value="Delete" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete selected messages?')) return false;" />
```

```php
$template->assign('script', 'messages');
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
  $action = makesafe($_POST['action']);
  $ids = $_POST['msgid'];
  if(!empty($ids))
  {
  if($action == 'delete')
  {
          foreach($ids as $k => $v)
          {
                 if(!empty($v))
                 {

                    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver = '"logged id"' AND msg_id = '$v' LIMIT 1")))
                        {
                            if(mysql_query("DELETE FROM messages WHERE msg_id = $v AND receiver = '"logged id"' LIMIT 1"))
                                {
                                    $success_msg = "Message(s) Deleted.";
                                }
                        }
                 }
          }
  }
  }
}
```

I tried using this code but it doesn't work,

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" name="delete" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete selected links?')) return false;" > <i class="icol-cross"></i> Delete </button>
```

I also want to validate if a user clicks the delete button without selecting any message (check box).

Comment: Sidenote. You have SQL vuln. in the code and using the deprecated mysql_* methods (these will stop working in the future..) Please put these issues firsthand

Answer (score 1):

For your confirm button, You should use the code as here:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" name="delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete selected links?')" > <i class="icol-cross"></i> Delete </button>
```

And for the SQL statement, I am not sure what do you expect to get when using both the quotation marks on both queries (aka '"logged in"'), I think you should use only one kind here, either ' or \", cause you are already wrapping this query with double quotes.

Good Luck !